# /me/home retrieves an outdated view of the News Feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

The FB docs at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ have been updated to say things like:

> /me/home retrieves an outdated view of the News Feed. This is currently a known issue and we don't have any near term plans to bring them back up into parity.

So, what is the preferred/best way to get the user's news feed?  Query the Stream table via FQL or does it have the same limitations?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure what you're asking as you already answered half of the question yourself. The News Feed became quite complex and to be honest, I'm not surprised it's not supported as an API method anymore.

Regarding FQL - you get the same connections as for the API (more or less) - I haven't seen anything in the FQL tables that would allow you to recreate the Feed precisely.

I would recommend asking for permissions to read Friend's feed and Liked pages statuses and recreate your own version of the News feed in the app.

Comment: I've queried the stream table via FQL, and I get the exact same "outdated" view as /me/home.